Emotion Analysis with bhadresh-savani/bert-base-uncased-emotion
Hope I can get some help here please!
I am trying to run an emotion analysis model from Hugging Face rep. (bhadresh-savani/bert-base-uncased-emotion) and I am struggling with the model run as it's extremely slow and also the output I am trying to get is not correct (I need to append the top emotion score next to my "Comment_new" variable). This is in Colab.
By running this model I am trying to get the top emotion for each review.I have attached a print of 3 reviews from the dataset which in total contains around 4K review lines.
Any idea please how I can run this fast and with the right output?
data sample, top 3 rows
Python Code
